# Intended behavior of required=true in composite component?

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component, mojarra

I'm a little bit confused about the `rquired="true"` attribute in a composite components.

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="Value: '#{cc.attrs.value}'" />    
</composite:implementation>
```

I'm expecting an error while using this composite without *value* like this `<my:test/>`, but the code will be rendered without any error or warning! I'm using Mojarra-2.1.19-jbossorg-1 and tested this issue with `@Named`  `@ViewScoped` and `@SeesionScoped` beans.

This is nearly the opposite than [Composite component required attribute throws exception in Mojarra 2.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085531), but there is actually asked about the behavior of `value=""`.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: No I still have no clue ...

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482024/composite-component-required-true-not-respected